# Reverse text of third column

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I have exported the SQL data to a text in Tab separted or comma separated format.

```
2       AX      Mariehamn       Mariehamn       ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12     2011-03-15 17:23:12     SYSTEM  Al-Ma
4       DZ      Adrar   Adrar   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12     2011-03-15 17:23:12     SYSTEM  Al-Ad
6       DZ      Ain Defla       Ain Defla       ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12     2011-03-15 17:23:12     SYSTEM  Al-Ai
8       DZ      Ain Temchent  Ain Temchent  ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12     2011-03-15 17:23:12     SYSTEM  Al-Ai
10      DZ      Shantanu   Shantanu   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12     2011-03-15 17:23:12     SYSTEM  Al-Al

2,"AX","Mariehamn","Mariehamn","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ma"
4,"DZ","Adrar","Adrar","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ad"
6,"DZ","Ain Defla","Ain Defla","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
8,"DZ","Ain Temchent","Ain Temchent","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
10,"DZ","Shantanu","Shantanu","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Al"
```

I need to reverse the text in third column as shown below, while keeping the other columns untouched.

```
nmaheiraM
rardA
alfeD niA
tnehcmeT niA
unatnahS
```

Any one of the above (TAB or CSV) formats can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use awk. For CSV,

```
$ awk -F"," '{for(i=length($3);i>=1;i--){s=s substr($3,i,1)};$3=s;s=""}1' OFS="," file
2,"AX","nmaheiraM","Mariehamn","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ma"
4,"DZ","rardA","Adrar","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ad"
6,"DZ","alfeD niA","Ain Defla","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
8,"DZ","tnehcmeT niA","Ain Temchent","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
10,"DZ","unatnahS","Shantanu","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Al"
```

or if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -i.bak -F"," -nae '$F[2].reverse! if $F[2];print $F.join(",")' file
```

Update: If you want to save the file, in awk just redirect to a temp file

eg

```
awk -F"," '{for(i=length($3);i>=1;i--){s=s substr($3,i,1)};$3=s;s=""}1' OFS="," file > temp && mv temp file
```

And by the way , in `sed`, its -i to save the file "inplace"

Comment: Thanks. # in sed I can use -e to replace the file. Is something similar possible in awk? Or I have to save > to.file and then move the file back?

Comment: `perl -i.bak -F, -lape'$F[2] = reverse $F[2]; $_ = join ",", @F' file`

Comment: @ikegami, please post your Perl solution as your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

see [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) - comma-separated values manipulator like,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
my @mydata;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                 or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
my $data = reverse($row->[2]);
 push(@mydata, $data);
 }
 print Dumper(\@mydata);
 $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
 close $fh;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'nmaheiraM',
          'rardA',
          'alfeD niA',
          'tnehcmeT niA',
          'unatnahS'
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest

```
perl -pe "@_=split ',',$_;$_[2]=scalar reverse $_[2];$_=join ',',@_;" <1.csv >2.csv
```

Its probably also possible to do with awk, but I've never used it.

Update: sorry, it worked in cmd, and I didn't check bash.
For bash it should look like this:

```
perl -aF/,/ -pe "\$F[2]=scalar reverse \$F[2];\$_=join ',',@F;" <1.csv
```

Comment: # syntax error at -e line 1, near "txt["  ## Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: use perl's `-a` and `-F` options to do the splitting for you (into array `@F`) -- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Comment: There's no need to redirect the input with <.  Just pass the filename as an argument to perl.  In general, that's a better practice since it gives perl access to the file name.

Answer (score 0):

To process file with either commas or tabulations delimiter, you can try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my @rows;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($delim) = $_ =~ /(,|\t)/;
    my @fields = split/,|\t/;
    $fields[2] = reverse $fields[2];
    push @rows, join $delim, @fields;
}
say Dumper \@rows;


__DATA__
2   AX  Mariehamn   Mariehamn   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ma
4   DZ  Adrar   Adrar   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ad
6   DZ  Ain Defla   Ain Defla   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ai
8   DZ  Ain Temchent    Ain Temchen ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ai
10  DZ  Shantanu    Shantanu    ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Al

2,"AX","Mariehamn","Mariehamn","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ma"
4,"DZ","Adrar","Adrar","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ad"
6,"DZ","Ain Defla","Ain Defla","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
8,"DZ","Ain Temchent","Ain Temchent","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"
10,"DZ","Shantanu","Shantanu","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Al"
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '2    AX  nmaheiraM   Mariehamn   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ma',
          '4    DZ  rardA   Adrar   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ad',
          '6    DZ  alfeD niA   Ain Defla   ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ai',
          '8    DZ  tnehcmeT niA    Ain Temchen ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Ai',
          '10   DZ  unatnahS    Shantanu    ACTIVE  2011-03-15 17:23:12 2011-03-15 17:23:12 SYSTEM  Al-Al',
          '',
          '2,"AX","nmaheiraM","Mariehamn","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ma"',
          '4,"DZ","rardA","Adrar","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ad"',
          '6,"DZ","alfeD niA","Ain Defla","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"',
          '8,"DZ","tnehcmeT niA","Ain Temchent","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Ai"',
          '10,"DZ","unatnahS","Shantanu","ACTIVE","2011-03-15 17:23:12","2011-03-15 17:23:12","SYSTEM","Al-Al"'
        ];
```